# How to install APK from PC?

Tags: android, installation, apk

I want to install an APK from PC to Android device. And because of user's Android and generally technical skills, I need to do it as automatically (silently) as possible. So how do I send an APK from PC to Android and start install there?

Comment: http://tech-papers.org/run_android_apps_on_chrome/

Comment: Use Airdroid app. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid

Comment: I had this same problem in the context of software development (needed to install file manager on a very reluctant device for which I was developing an app that would access the sd card), so I think it's not off-topic.

Comment: -I'm facing issue to update in same way....
-update version and generate signed apk
-when tap to install it prompts for updates but at the end show "App not install"???

any solution for this as i'm developing an app and wan to update on my physical device.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

```
adb install <path_to_apk>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#move

Comment: And when I need to install apk from their PC?

Comment: You can host your apk at [http://]yoursite/your.apk then ask them to open this link in browser. Then it shall download the apk file and ask for permission to install.

Comment: If they use Gmail, you can email the APK to them, and when they receive the email in the Android Gmail client the email has an "Install" button on it. Installing apps via Gmail is very easy, however do note that before anyone can install an app from a source other than the Android Market, they must set the "Unknown sources" setting on their device, to allow installation of apps from places other than the Android Market (Google Play!)

Comment: Remember in 4.2+ enable first adb Debugging.  
Quoted from above link: In order to use adb with a device connected over USB, you must enable USB debugging in the device system settings, under Developer options.

On Android 4.2 and higher, the Developer options screen is hidden by default. To make it visible, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options at the bottom.

Comment: Can't access that in China.  What if the site goes down.  Post a local tutorial.  Why is this even marked as an answer? -1

Comment: @OllieC Does the Gmail alternative work with a Debug version of the app?

Answer (score 125):

1. Connect Android device to PC via USB cable and [turn on USB storage](http://www.device-recovery.com/how-to-connect-android-devices-to-pc-with-usb-mass-storage-mode).
2. Copy .apk file to attached device's storage.
3. Turn off USB storage and disconnect it from PC.
4. Check the option Settings → Applications → Unknown sources
   OR Settings > Security > Unknown Sources.
5. Open FileManager app and click on the copied .apk file.  If you can't fine the apk file try searching or allowing hidden files.
   It will ask you whether to install this app or not. Click Yes or OK.

This procedure works even if ADB is not available.

Comment: If you don't have a file-browser, you can't install file-browser to install files. However, you CAN open a .apk by browsing with... THE BROWSER: file://path/to/app.apk

Comment: If you don't have a FileManager app installed you can download and install it from Google Play. It's free, but it shows advertising. It's able to install .apk files.

Comment: It's a very useful answer generally but this process can't be automated easily, probably this is the reason why wasn't it accepted.

Comment: If you do not have a file manager and you cannot install it then it is possible to upload apk via bluetooth. Once transferred tap the file to install.

Comment: @LeosLiterak Most phones have a download-manager-app so you don't need an filebrowser for installing.

Comment: Check the option Settings → Security → Unknown sources.

Comment: What folder do you put the apk file in?  Android?  Download?  or just the root folder?

Comment: Michael Paulukonis's suggestion on using the Browser if your stock Android does not have a file browser is excellent.  On my Android 5 system I used chrome to browse to file:///sdcard/ (not that it is 3 slashes after file:) to click on an apk I transferred from PC via MTP.

Comment: On Google Pixel, the path to allow installation using File Manager is slightly different:     From a Home screen, navigate to Settings >  Apps & notifications >  Advanced >  Special app access >  Install unknown apps > 
    Select the unknown app/source then tap the Allow from this source switch to turn on or off

Answer (score 9):

Just connect the device to the PC with a USB cable, then copy the .apk file to the device. On the device, touch the APK file in the file explorer to install it.

You could also offer the .apk on your website. People can download it, then touch it to install.

Answer (score 6):

[3 Ways to Install Applications On Android Without The Market](http://maketecheasier.com/install-applications-without-the-market/2011/01/28)

And don't forget to enable Unknown sources in your Android device Settings, before installing apk, else Android platform will not allow you to install apk directly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Airdroid , android market install the app on android then go onto the computer type in the address given, type in the password given (or scan the QR code). Go to settings and under security (if your running the new ICS or Jellybean) or go to settings->apps->managment and select unknown sources(for gingerbread) then click on (I think) speed install, or something along those lines. it will be on the top of the page slightly towards the left. drag and drop as many .apks as you want then on you android just tap the install buttons that appear. Airdroid is wonderful and does a lot more than just apks.

Comment: S/He wants to it as automatically as possible. I think it's not automatic enough to ask a user to transfer apk files to their phone, open those files via a file manager in their phone and click the install button.

Answer (score 0):

try using sendanywhere that is used to manage files between in wireless manner
[send any where](https://send-anywhere.com/) this transfer through any platform and

another method is bluetooth if the apk is less than 10mb or so.
[bluetooth transfer](https://www.techlicious.com/how-to/how-to-share-file-between-android-phone-and-pc-bluetooth/)